# First-chance exception: KernelBase.dll

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, access-violation

I'm trying to build and run this piece of program with VS2012 Pro.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    //allocate memory
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    //create child process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,    //use command line
             L"mspaint.exe",    //command line
             NULL,    //don't inherit process handle
             NULL,    //don't inherit thread handle
             FALSE,    //disable handle inheritance
             0,        //no creation flags
             NULL,    //use parent's environment block
             NULL,    //use parent's existing directory
             &si,
             &pi))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Create Process Failed");
        return -1;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'G:\workspace\VS2012\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>
> 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x763919E3 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00CB586E.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x763919E3 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00CB586E.
>
> The program '[6992] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Note that I built it without no error (the file stdafx.h contains all the headers that I need).

I searched for this error, but could not find out any solution, and this is only a simple program, so I can't understand what's the problem here :(.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program first? Try to use the full path to mspaint.exe .

Comment: Thanks, but "system32" folder is ALWAYS one of the first folders that system try to find any executable files you call :). And I have to debug the program to get the error "First-chance exception..."
Otherwise, I built and ran the correlative code with GCC (mingw) with no error.

Comment: Delete everything then add each line back one at a time. Also there's no c++ here.

Comment: Access violation means, that you are trying to access a location in memory that is invalid (NULL-pointer for example). Insert a breakpoint before WaitForSingleObject and see it the program manages to go there (debug by pressing F5).

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for CreateProcess? No? You might want to read the bit where it says the command line parameter to CreateProcess has to be WRITABLE by the process. And your constant string is not writable.

Comment: The pertinent part is this: The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/01/9673254.aspx for some explanation of the issue that SecurityMatt pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the CreateProcessW documentation, specifically about your second parameter:

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation

So in answer to your question, don't pass a constant string literal as the second parameter to that function, or you'll get an AV.

Comment: But the problem now is "Run-Time check failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'progPath' was corrupted."

Comment: @SandDust: Looks like your code has a stack overflow in it then. Are you putting too many characters into your buffer?

Comment: I think no, I use 'progPath' to store the path to the executable file:

    wchar_t progPath;
    wcout << L"Input path ";
    wcin.getline( &progPath, 80, '\n' );

    LPWSTR prog = &progPath;

Comment: In that code you just posted, progPath is a buffer of only one character. You probably want something more like wchar_t progPath[MAX_PATH]

Comment: Thanks, I just made a BIG mistake, I forgot [MAX_PATH]